# vlad tasks: after update, before symlink

Tags: ruby, rake, vlad-deployer

We're using vlad the deployer to deploy our rails app.

Currently, we have some tasks that run after the vlad:update task.   These tasks take a few minutes.   During those few minutes, the site is broken.

I'd like to run those tasks in the middle of vlad:update -- after it has done everything except create the "current" symlink.   How do I do that?   the vlad:update task appears to be monolothic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.   Define your task to run before the `update_symlinks` task rather than after the `update` task.

```
remote_task :finish_deployment, :roles => :app do
  ...
end

remote_task :update_symlinks => :finish_deployment
```

Comment: note that doing it this way means that finish_deployment will also run before the symlinks from shared are created, which may affect your logs, et cetera.